# How to switch between Bake and Material view quickly?

Tags: materials, interface, baking

How can I switch between a new material I created with a texture bake and the three original materials in one object in Blender, without needing to manually reassign the materials? I want to be able to preview the material with bake and then switch back to the original three materials simply without needing to delete them or use 'Ctrl+Z' to undo the assignments. Is there a more efficient way to perform this switch? Without also needing to clone the object.

[image]